# Reading call log entries-number, name and duration, Rejected by Play Store even with READ_CALLLOG, dialer permission

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play

We are building a app to read call log entries - basically we try to read the number, name and duration of the last few calls. we have updated the manifest with READ_CALLLOG permission. Also we have ensured that the app is made as the default dialer app.

But the app is getting rejected from playstore. Please refer the below screen shot.

can someone help us on this?

Manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.MyApp.Myapp" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="2.8.9" android:versionCode="17">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
<application android:label="MyApp365" android:icon="@drawable/appiconFinal" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
<activity android:name="MyApp365.Droid.SplashActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:exported="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Google is considering the users privacy seriously. Starting from Android Marshmallow, it has segregated dangerous permissions and introduced Runtime permissions. With Android Pie, the apps which are idle can no longer access microphone, camera, and sensors. NOW, it has updated its Google Play Developer Policy which restricting SMS, CALL_LOG access only to default apps.Read full article
[No more SMS & Call Log permissions](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827)

Answer (score 0):

Apps that fail to meet policy requirements or submit a Permissions Declaration Form by 9 January 2019 may be [removed from Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?source=post_page---------------------------).

With Android Pie, the apps which are idle can no longer access microphone, camera, and sensors. NOW, it has updated its Google Play Developer Policy which restricting SMS, CALL_LOG access only to default apps and [click here for detail](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/?source=post_page---------------------------)

**Solution:**

1) If you have an app in the play store, requesting SMS or CALL_LOG permissions and your app doesn’t really require these permissions, you should be removing it from the AndroidManifest file and should update the app in play store.

2) If you really need these permissions to fulfill certain functionalities, you should be filling 6-page [Permission Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform?source=post_page---------------------------) and submitting to Google Play for review.